# Jquery $.post script runs three times (multiple INSERT)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, insert

I use this script to create a data in my mysql database.
But when i create the project, it insert 3 times the project.

First i thought it could be that i push to often the submit button.
So i add to the form a .submit function. But didn't solved the multiple insert.

***The HTML Index.html***

```
   <div id='pageContent'></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customBtn').prop('disabled', false);

    // VIEW USERS on load of the page
    $('#loaderImage').show();
    showUsers();

    // clicking the 'VIEW USERS' button
    $('#viewUsers').click(function(){
        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show();

        showUsers();


    });

    // clicking the '+ NEW USER' button
    $('#addUser').click(function(){
        showCreateUserForm();
    });

    // clicking the EDIT button
    $(document).on('click', '.editBtn', function(){ 

        var user_id = $(this).closest('td').find('.userId').text();
        console.log(user_id);

        // show a loader image
        $('#loaderImage').show();

        // read and show the records after 1 second
        // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
        // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('update_form.php?user_id=" + user_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });
        setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/update_form.php?user_id=" + user_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);

    }); 


    // when clicking the DELETE button
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(){ 
        if(confirm('Möchten Sie dieses Projekt löschen?')){

            // get the id
            var user_id = $(this).closest('td').find('.userId').text();

            // trigger the delete file
            $.post("cure/delete.php", { id: user_id })
                .done(function(data) {
                    // you can see your console to verify if record was deleted
                    console.log(data);

                    $('#loaderImage').show();

                    // reload the list
                    showUsers();

                });

        }
    });


    // CREATE FORM IS SUBMITTED
     $(document).on('submit', '#addUserForm', function() {

        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show();

        // post the data from the form
        $.post("cure/create.php", $(this).serialize())
            .done(function(data) {
                // 'data' is the text returned, you can do any conditions based on that
                showUsers();
            });
        return false;

    });

    // UPDATE FORM IS SUBMITTED
     $(document).on('submit', '#updateUserForm', function() {

        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show();

        // post the data from the form
        $.post("cure/update.php", $(this).serialize())
            .done(function(data) {
                // 'data' is the text returned, you can do any conditions based on that
                showUsers();
            });

        return false;
    });

});

// READ USERS
function showUsers(){
    var kom_id = {{user::id}};
    console.log(kom_id);
    // read and show the records after at least a second
    // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
    // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('read.php', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });
    // THIS also hides the loader image
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/read.php?kompetenzpartner=" + kom_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);
} 

// CREATE USER FORM
function showCreateUserForm(){
    var kom_id_2 = {{user::id}};
    console.log(kom_id_2);
    // show a loader image
    $('#loaderImage').show();
    // read and show the records after 1 second
    // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
    // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('read.php');
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/create_form.php?kompetenzpartner=" + kom_id_2 + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);
}


</script>
```

***create.php***

```
<?php

//include database connection
include 'libs/db_connect.php';

try{

    //write query
    $query = "INSERT INTO table SET project = ?, name = ?, tstamp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";

    //prepare query for excecution
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);

    //bind the parameters

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['project']);

    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['name']);  

    // Execute the query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Ok.";
    }else{
        echo "Bad";
    }

}

//to handle error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```

***And the create_form.php***

```
<script>
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.customBtn').prop("disabled", true);
}); 
</script>
<form id='addUserForm' action='#' method='post' border='0'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>Project</td>";
            <td><input type='text' name='project' required></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            echo "<td>Name</td>";
            <td><input type='text' name='name' required></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">        
            <?php if($landcode == "de"): {
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Speichern' class='customBtn'>";
            }
            else: {
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Save' class='customBtn'>"; }
            endif;
            ?>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And when i have a look at the Chrome Developer-Tool i see that it sends 3 times the create.php. So someone know how can i handle this? Or fix it?!
[Here a screenshot of the chrome tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw0x2.png)

Comment: Are other `form` elements on page ? Can post `html` ?

Comment: No there is only one form at the create_form.php . i use this tutorial http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/05/crud-with-php-jquery.html

Comment: Not certain, perhaps same issue as posted below. `button` or `input` `element`s `submit`ting multiple times. Does `type="submit"` attribute at `input` elements fire `event` 3 times for 1 `click` or `submit` ? Difficult to isolate, yet appears there are multiple `event`s attached to elements, i.e.g., `submit`, and `click` and then `$.post()` ?

Comment: But thats the whole code :) There are only two other things a update form + update.php and a delete.php . But they are loaded when user hit button "edit" or "delete". So i try in other browser there it works. After that i switch back to chrome and the error didn't come again. So i will test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `form` submitting 3 times due to 3 instances of submission. 1) if a `button` `click` `event` is utilized to `submit` `form`; 2) the `.submit()` method at top of post *"**in the form**"*, then; 3) at `$.post()`.

Not certain without `html` posted. Could probably accomplish with *1* of above 3.

Edit

Note

Not certain about `#viewUsers`, `.editBtn`, `.deleteBtn`, `#updateUserForm` does
not appear as `html` within `index.html`. Please clarify those elements`
tags present ?

Also. `setTimeout` could be substituted for `.show(1000, function() {/* callback */})`
at `showUsers()` and `showCreateUsersForm`

There may still be some redundancy present below. Perhaps try substitute `click`
for `submit` as `event`, mapped to `click` of an `button` or `input type='button'` 
element ?

If possible, post all `html` from `index.html`.

Not certain about `php` within document, or in `php files.

Try

```
<div id='pageContent'></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.customBtn').prop('disabled', false);

    // VIEW USERS on load of the page
    $('#loaderImage').show(0, function() {
      showUsers();
    });


    // clicking the 'VIEW USERS' button
    $('#viewUsers').click(function() {
        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show(0, function() {
      showUsers();
    });

    // clicking the '+ NEW USER' button
    $('#addUser').click(function(){
        showCreateUserForm();
    });

    // clicking the EDIT button
    $(document).on('click', '.editBtn', function(e) { 

        var user_id = $(e.target).closest('td').find('.userId').text();
        console.log(user_id);

        // show a loader image
        $('#loaderImage').show(1000, function() {
          $('#pageContent').load('cure/update_form.php?user_id=" + user_id + "', function() { 
            $('#loaderImage').hide(); 
          });
       });

        // read and show the records after 1 second
        // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
        // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('update_form.php?user_id=" + user_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });
        //setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/update_form.php?user_id=" + user_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);

    }); 


    // when clicking the DELETE button
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() { 
        if ( confirm('Möchten Sie dieses Projekt löschen?') ) {

            // get the id
            var user_id = $(e.target).closest('td').find('.userId').text();

            // trigger the delete file
            $.post("cure/delete.php", { id: user_id })
                .done(function(data) {
                    // you can see your console to verify if record was deleted
                    console.log(data);

                    $('#loaderImage').show(0, function() {
                                          // reload the list
                    showUsers();
                    });



                });

        };
    });


    // CREATE FORM IS SUBMITTED
     $(document).on('click', '#submitForm', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show(0, function() {
                  // post the data from the form
        $.post("cure/create.php", $(this).serialize())
            .done(function(data) {
                // 'data' is the text returned, you can do any conditions based on that
                showUsers();
            });

        });


        return false;

    });

    // UPDATE FORM IS SUBMITTED
     $(document).on('click', '#updateUserForm', function() {

        // show a loader img
        $('#loaderImage').show();

        // post the data from the form
        $.post("cure/update.php", $(this).serialize())
            .done(function(data) {
                // 'data' is the text returned, you can do any conditions based on that
                showUsers();
            });

        return false;
    });

//});

// READ USERS
function showUsers(){
    var kom_id = {{user::id}};
    console.log(kom_id);
    // read and show the records after at least a second
    // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
    // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('read.php', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });
    // THIS also hides the loader image
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/read.php?kompetenzpartner=" + kom_id + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);
} 

// CREATE USER FORM
function showCreateUserForm(){
    var kom_id_2 = {{user::id}};
    console.log(kom_id_2);
    // show a loader image
    $('#loaderImage').show();
    // read and show the records after 1 second
    // we use setTimeout just to show the image loading effect when you have a very fast server
    // otherwise, you can just do: $('#pageContent').load('read.php');
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('cure/create_form.php?kompetenzpartner=" + kom_id_2 + "', function(){ $('#loaderImage').hide(); });",1000);
}

})
</script>


//2
<script>
/*
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.customBtn').prop("disabled", true);
}); 
*/
</script>
<form id='addUserForm' action='#' method='post' border='0'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            echo "<td>Project</td>";
            <td><input type='text' name='project' required></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            echo "<td>Name</td>";
            <td><input type='text' name='name' required></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">        
            <?php if($landcode == "de"): {
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Speichern' class='customBtn'>";
            }
            else: {
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Save' class='customBtn'>"; }
            endif;
            ?>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
// submit `form` on `click` instead of utilizing `submit` event.
<input type="button" id="submitForm" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```